# Including info about the company on a product page?

Tags: website-design, content, content-strategy, product

I am designing a company website for a software company that has been around since 1995. Their current software is horrible and outdated, and so the company is in the process of creating a completely new, web-based application to replace the old one.

I have created a website page for the new software, and my boss wants to add some (B.S.) statements about the company directly on the product page, which relates to the business they had with the old software.

I worry that the lines about the company are not only ineffective, but confusing to put on a product page that is for a brand new product.

For example:

Introducing a **brand new** software that does [abc task]!

About Company:
Company has supplied [abc task] software for 21 years!
Company is the 3rd largest supplier of software for [abc task]!

I am unsure about the idea of adding info about the company to a product page- can't say I've seen any such thing on any competitors page - especially since it doesn't relate to the product in any way.

Is this actually a beneficial addition, and if not, are there any arguments against I can present to my boss?

Comment: It could be, yes. It probably isn't in its current form. But the boss is essentially thinking in terms of a customer thinking "New [abc task] software, eh? You know that's a difficult thing, why do these guys think they can write it?" That might not be the best way to do it, but talk about their concerns with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not simply want to tell them "no", you could suggest to make the company BS part longer. Let them add some key milestones of the company. Then, after you have a nice long writeup, it will "obviously be too long to fit on the product page". You make a separate page for it and put a nice little unobtrusive link on your product page.

Aside from that, you might just explain (in writing) why you think it is a very bad idea. If the boss still insists, then do exactly as he says. It is his company and his success, not yours. You display due diligence, but then it's time to move on. It's not a case where lives are at stake.

Answer (score 1):

I would just design a really good BS page about the company and say to your boss that it's much more effective on its own page.

Make it so good that your boss will go for it, and then link to it from your product page with a line like ***Why you should buy from us*** or something similar.